# NSView loses mouseMoved/mouseDragged if dragged in from subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

A = the parent NSView;
B = the child NSView;

B has a small NSTrackingArea;
B is a small subview of A;

A correctly receives mouseMoved and mouseDragged events if moved,clicked, dragged in a empty area.

If i click in B and drag the mouse outside of its bounds into A, A does not receive any mouseMoved or mouseDragged events.

Can someone point me to what i could do to get the superview A to react to this drag?

Comment: do you have a mouseDragged implemented higher in the view-hierarchy/ responder-chain? if you set a breakpoint in that function, does it get called when you go outside viewA bounds?

Answer (score 0):

I've observed this and I was able to solve it by doing as follows:

1. Create a NSViewController and set viewA as its "view" property.
2. In my case, I implemented mouseDragged in the view-controller but
   you can try on the view and see what results you get. mouseEntered
   and mouseExited were implemented in the view subclass.

Tip: Make sure you're updating the tracking area bounds as needed.
Hope this helps.